# Save Visio document to web with multiple hyperlinks per object

Tags: visio

We have a process flow document that requires multiple hyperlinks per object. It appears that the only the [VML web format](http://blog.bvisual.net/2013/06/18/comparison-of-visio-save-as-web-outputs/) supports this.

We recently upgraded from Visio 2003 to 2010. Now, when we go to save the document as a web file it is missing the publish button, which would [appear to stop us from](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/publish-button-missing-in-visio-2010/26cb3c39-c980-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) to choose VML as an output, even as contradictory information says that [VML is still an option](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/32ced63c-6b4f-4031-a860-9c103b481a9a/can-visio-2010-save-as-web-page-without-forcing-end-users-to-use-silverlight?forum=visiogeneral).

How can we get Visio to save to web in VML format so that we can have multiple hyperlinks per object?

Answer (score 1):

Visio 2010 Standard has a longstanding bug where the publish button does not show up. The fix is to:

1. Select the File tab, and choose "Save As"
2. Choose the folder where you want to save the file
3. Add the file name and extension (.html) with quotes around it, such as "MyDrawing.html"
4. Leave the File type as 'drawing'.
5. Press Save
6. Set the output filetype as .vml

You will only need to do this one time, as it saves the settings.